# Configuring Hibernate with grails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails

I have created created a Grails application and created the Spring Security plugin set up into It.

When I run the application I get following error. Hibernate folder is empty. Can anyone help me resolve this?

```
2014-06-20 13:41:26,946 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] ERROR [/GrailsLoginWithSpring].[gsp]  - 
Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/GrailsLoginWithSpring] threw exception
Message: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'org.grails.internal.SESSION_FACTORY_HOLDER': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3720a15d' of type 
[org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.ConfigurableLocalSessionFactoryBean] 
while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3720a15d': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] 
cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
hibernate {
  reload = false
}
```

As suggested by Graeme Rocher in this [JIRA](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8805)

Comment: Hi gotomanners thanks for the response but i still get below error. Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: Your solution made the trick gotomanners. I had multiple Java Instance running so code change was not reflecting. Thank You! One more small clarification. Untill i need a customized hibernate functioning i need not create a hibernate.cfg.xml in grails. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @9000492 Glad this helped you! 
Yes, I haven't worked with a customized hibernate so I never had to use a hibernate.cfg.xml yet.